# Google Sheets Double Lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out a way to lookup specific information from different tables. I have one table with teams and the points they have scored depending on the Week.

[image: Scores]

A second table with the Schedule and Matchups

[image: Matchups]

I'm trying to cross reference the two tables so I can enter information in a third table.

[image: Scores Against]

I first was trying double VLOOKUP, but I'm not sure if that is possible as I wasn't having any success. I'm able to get an Array that is close to the information I need so I can perform the VLOOKUP, but I'm unable to perform the second VLOOKUP to get the score of TEAM B.

[image: Temp Array]

I was able to solve this issue with a helper column to combine the information, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Demo Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18LKD_IwfulaSSAdHJ6qtISCF5kY4IgD32lJzZqKfqfY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you make the demo editable (it's currently view Only) I think i have something that will work

Comment: I believed I have changed it so you can edit. Thanks!

Comment: If those tables are all on separate tabs in the real sheet, could you put them in separate tabs on this sample?

Comment: They are all on a single sheet. It'll be my Data Table sheet.

Comment: I was able to get both suggestions working on my actual sheet. MattKing's was a little simpler to follow. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will work in just the top left corner of your "opposing" results table as demonstrated in the new tab called MK.Help.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(B18:B19&C17:F17,{B11:B14&D11:D14,E11:E14;B11:B14&E11:E14,D11:D14},2,0),C3:F5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B18:B19),1,2),0))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put this formula on cell C18 and drag to down and right:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($B18,$B$4:$F$5,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(IF($B18=$B$11:$B$14,(C$17=$D$11:$E$14)*ROW($D$11:$D$14),"")),IF(MAX(IF($B18=$B$11:$B$14,(C$17=$D$11:$E$14)*COLUMN($D$10:$E$10),""))=4,5,4))),$C$3:$F$3,0)+1,0))
```

I have already put the answer on your sample sheet.